# Binomial queue in forest?

Tags: forest, trees

I was hoping to get some help drawing a binomial queue with the forest package. All I can find are references to binomial trees, but I am looking to replicate this:

[image]

I tried using phantom to make spaces but it didn't really work how I wanted it to:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle,l=14mm,s sep=10mm,draw}
  [23
    [,phantom]
    [51]
    [24
      [,phantom]
      [65]
    ]
  ]
 \end{forest}
```

[image]

Any help it much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple rude solution:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={circle,l=14mm,s sep=10mm,draw}
[23
    [,phantom]
    [,phantom]
    [51]
    [24
        [,phantom]
        [65]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

a little bit more "advance" solution

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={circle, l=14mm, s sep=7mm, draw, 
          calign=first} % <---
[23
    [,phantom]
    [51]
    [24
        [,phantom]
        [65]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result is similar as before.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to avoid the `phantoms` altogether by using `calign=fixed edge angles`, as in the manual on the top of p. 41. And I would define a style for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{binomial queue/.style={calign=fixed edge angles,calign primary
angle=30,calign secondary angle=60,
  for tree={if n children={1}{grow=-60}{calign=fixed edge
  angles,calign primary angle=30,calign secondary angle=60},
  circle,draw,text width=width("23"),align=center}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  binomial queue
  [23
    [51]
    [24
      [65]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
  binomial queue,
  for tree={s sep+=1em}
  [12
    [21]
    [24
      [65]
    ]
    [14
      [26]
      [16
        [18]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Replaced `where` by `if` as suggested by @cfr, thanks!

Comment: @cfr Thanks! Even if I was not as jet lagged as I am now, I would most likely miss these subtle but important points. I'll correct it ASAP.